# Excerpt isn't working with file contents

Tags: php, string

```
$excerpt= excerpt(file_get_contents("data/file.txt"), 30);
echo $excerpt;

function excerpt($str, $chars){
    $index = strripos($str, ' ');
    return substr($str, 0, $index)."...";
}
```

It don't return the text stripped at the 30 characters or less. It returns the whole text without the last word and the dots added but if you use a string typed manually it works perfect.

Why this isn't working if content is loaded from a text file? I think that the /n's are broking the strripos.

Comment: Define "isn't working". What does the text file contain? What results do you get?

Comment: It don't return the text stripped at the 30 characters or less.

Comment: It returns the whole text without the last word and the dots added.

Comment: Your function doesn't ever use that `$chars` argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use stripos, not strripos.

```
<?php

$excerpt= excerpt(file_get_contents("data/file.txt"), 30);
echo $excerpt;

function excerpt($str, $chars){
    $index = stripos($str, " ", $chars);
    return substr($str, 0, $index)."...";
}

?>
```

Comment: Heck, he can just use `strpos()` since he's not looking for an alphabetic character.

Comment: voted up, but should be using strpos() if matching a static, non-alpha string like `" "`.

Comment: True, but he may want to make it configurable at a later time - in which you would need to use case insensitivity.  There is negligible  additional load using this function.

Comment: @Andrew Sledge this doesn't solve his issue! @scoates please pay attention

Comment: @Andrew Sledge sorry, I didn't see you added the $chars param to stripos, i thought you just replaced strripos in his example :) also, check out my example for a more friendly trim of text, without cutting words in half too ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not related to the `stripos` usage. As I can see you're trying to trim the string at 30 characters without cutting words in half. In order to do that you need to correct your `excerpt` function:

```
function excerpt($str, $chars) {
//no need to trim, already shorter than wanted dimension    
if (strlen($tr) <= $chars) {        
    return $str;    
}       

//find last space within wanted dimension   
$last_space = strrpos(substr($str, 0, $chars), ' ');    
$trimmed_text = substr($str, 0, $last_space);

return $trimmed_text . '...';
}
```

and yes, your function doesn't even use the $chars param...

Answer (score 0):

I gues you want an excerpt with as many whole words as possible.
Some tips:

If you only just want the first 3o chars you should not read the whole file!

What you should do: read only to the maximum excerpt lenght and then format it.

```
function readExcerpt($path){
    $fhand = fopen($path,"r");
    $excerpt = fread($fhand ,30);
    fclose($fhand);
    return $excerpt;
}

    function fromatExcerpt($excerpt){
       //remove last word/word fragment
       $index = strripos($excerpt,' ');
       if($index!==false){
          $excerpt= substr($excerpt,0,$index);
       }
       return $excerpt.'...';  
    }

    echo fromatExcerpt(readExcerpt("D:\hotfix.txt"));
```